# On inequality of exponentially activated, unit transform of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $x$ be a vector and $A$ a matrix. Let 
$$
y := \dfrac{Ax}{\lVert A \rVert} 
$$
bet a unit transform of vector $x$,
and 
$$
\widehat{y}:=  y/\lVert x\rVert
$$ the same transformation with normalization on $x$. Also define a vector $z$ point-wisely by
$$
z:=e^y
$$
with $ \overline{z} := z/\lVert z \rVert$.

**Question**. Suppose $\widehat{y}_1>\widehat{y}_2$ (or equivalently $y_1 >y_2$) where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the first and second elements of $y$, respectively. Then 
$$
\overline{z}_1 - \overline{z}_2 \geq \widehat{y}_1 - \widehat{y}_2?
$$

The assumption that the transformation is a unit one might be removed; we might simply replace $A/\lVert A \rVert$ by $ M$. Would it then be easier to prove or disprove?

**Additional Assumption**. Suppose $x$ is such that $y_i >0$ for all $i$ and $y_1 = \max y_i$.

Comment: When you are comparing two vectors, are you comparing them element wise?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Sorry for unclear writing. I will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be identity matrix, $x = (4a, a, 8a)$. Then $\hat y = (\frac{4}{9}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{8}{9})$ and $\hat y_1 - \hat y_2 = \frac{1}{3}$.

But $\|z\| > e^{8a}$ so $\bar z_1 < e^{-4a}$. As $\bar z_2 > 0$ we have $\bar z_1 - \bar z_2 < e^{-4a}$, so for large enough $a$ we have $\bar z_1 - \bar z_2 < \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sincerely. But since the derivative of $e^y$ is smaller than linear one when $y_i<0$, I think the above conjecture would not hold. And you provided a counter example. Sorry to bother but how about when $x$ is such that all the components $y_i>0$

Comment: In my example all $y_i > 0$.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but what if $y_1 = \max y_i$?

Comment: Take $x = (4 \varepsilon, 3 \varepsilon)$ for some small $\varepsilon$. Then $\hat y_1 - \hat y_2 = \frac{1}{5}$, but $\bar z_1 - \bar z_2 \approx \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Comment: Would you expect the above claim hold if $x$ is lower bounded sufficiently so? Like, for some $b$, $\lVert x \rVert >b$. If you know, may I ask you some reverse Cauchy inequality that can be applied to the above case?

Comment: If we omit $A$ then it probably is, but I can't came with formal sentence. I believe it's better to be asked as separate question - much more people will notice a question then comments buried in existent question.

Comment: And of course if we don't omit $A$, lower bound on $x$ is irrelevant, as $\frac{A}{\|A\|}$ can decrease norm.